# scala monte carlo estimator of pi (as short as possible)

Tags: scala

Happy Pi Day everyone! For no reason at all, I'm trying to construct a Monte Carlo estimator of Pi that is as short as possible. Can we construct one that can fit in a tweet?

Here's what what I have

```
Seq.fill(1000)(Random.nextFloat).zip(Seq.fill(1000)(Random.nextFloat)).map{case (a,b) => a*a + b*b <1}.map(if (_) 1 else 0).reduce(_+_).toFloat / 1000 * 4
```

So this esimates Pi correctly, but is about 15 characters too long fit into a tweet. Can we do any better? The obvious problem (to me) is the verbosity of generating random numbers `Seq.fill(1000)(Random.nextFloat)`, any clever way around that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems belong on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/, not on Stackoverflow. It seems asker is not interested in solving any real problem. The Code Golf site seems like a place exactly for this type of questions.

Comment: The only whitespace you need is around the `else`, and you can replace `.toFloat` by using `1F`, which by my count gets you under 140. That doesn't include the import for `Random`, though, so it feels like cheating.

Comment: This is a little bit shorter: `def xs = Seq.fill(1000)(util.Random.nextFloat); (xs, xs).zipped.map((a,b) => if (a*a + b*b < 1) 1F else 0F).sum/1000*4`

Comment: `def r = math.random; Seq.fill(1000)(r, r).map{case(a,b) ⇒ if (a*a + b*b < 1) 1 else 0}.sum/250d` Still the if to remove.

Comment: Without the If (84 chars): `def r=math.random;Seq.fill(1000)(r,r).map{case(a,b)⇒ ~(a*a+b*b-.5).round+2}.sum/250d` I am sure there is more elegant.

Comment: Yeah I guess this would do better on codegolf, but thanks for your thoughts everyone! Thanks for the informative answer Lomig, I learned a couple things I didn't know about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible shorter solution (70 chars without the unnecessary spaces).

```
def r = math.random; Seq.fill(1000)(r,r).count{case (a,b) ⇒ a*a + b*b < 1} / 250d
```

To keep this response in the scope of StackOverflow, here are some useful Scala features:

- Use [`math.random`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.math.package@random:Double) to generate random Double numbers;
- The `(r,r)` snippet uses the Scala [automatic tupling](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3583);
- The [`count()`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce@count(p:A=%3EBoolean):Int) method;
- Usage of the unicode symbol `⇒` for the right double arrow;
- The `d` in `250d` will create a Double instead of an Int.